# "Unknown column in 'field list'"when trying to post thread

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a simple forum in which you can log in to post threads. I have a users table and a topics table. When you post a thread it sends information to the topics table containing id, title, message, date and username. The problem is that I can only post threads when logged in with a username containing only digits. I noticed that i had the topic_by (username) on INT which i changed to VARCHAR. That didn't fix the problem though, it still only works if you have only digits in your username. If you try to post with a username containing letters the following line shows up:

Unknown column 'asd' in 'field list'

I have tried deleting and remaking the table.

This is the code that sends the data:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(topic_id, topic_title, topic_message, topic_date, topic_by)
      VALUES ('NULL', '$title', '$message', '$datetime', ".$_SESSION["username"].")";
```

When you register an account it sends data to the users table including user_name and THAT works with letters and/or digits even though the topic_by row has the same properties.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to insert`".$_SESSION["username"]."` without surrounding with quotes `'` wich are needed since it's not an integer field. This will makes your database understand your actual `username` as a column. Simply use quote `'".$_SESSION["username"]."'`.

So your code will look like that

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (topic_id, topic_title, topic_message, topic_date, topic_by) VALUES ('NULL', '$title', '$message', '$datetime', '".$_SESSION["username"]."')";
```

Anyway i would strongly suggest you to use `prepared statements` to avoid any security risk, you can read a nice tutorial about `PDO` [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: No, please, do not change your code to that. Get some variable filtering in there for security's sake! You're just asking for a Bobby Tables case. And no, PDO is not a magic kill-all-vulnerabilities pill.